# ISP and ssh tunneling

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I have a question about ssh tunneling.
Is it possible for the ISP to realize the destination server which I want to connect it via ssh tunneling? I mean the destination website which I want to visit it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, but not the reason you may think off directly. The problem is that your traffic is secure so your ISP can't see what you are sending, and if you are using just IPs, he won't even see whereto you are connecting (he will only see traffic flowing between you and your SSH server). The problem is that you need to take care of your DNS requests. If you connect to a site you will probably use UDP for performing a DNS request. UDP can't pass a SSH tunnel as it's connection oriented.

So this means that your DNS request is sent unencrypted and your ISP will be able to see it, therefor disclosing to which website you are connecting when using a domain name.

Comment: He can use sshuttle --dns to avoid that. https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle

Comment: Indeed there are other ways as well, but it's not default behavior